How to implement CDC from Greenplum?
We need catch data changes from Greenplum(catch insert/update/delete from GP database)
Do you know any methods of software to help catch data from Greenplum?

If you do not care much about transaction compatibility, you can use debezium to handle each node of Greenplum, debezium has supported Postgres, you can set up each connection to each node, and treat each node as one Postgres node, then replay the data change to the target. But it has not transaction compatibility.
Now Greenplum team is going to release the a version of GPDB CDC to support transaction compatibility in September 2024.
